# Preventing Antivirus from saying my gmail winform has virus

Tags: c#, winforms, gmail, antivirus

I'm working on a basic project where my WinForm sends the users inputs to any gmail.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
   SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.customsmtp.com");
   mail.From = new MailAddress("fromEmail@fromemail.com");
   mail.To.Add("toemail@toemail.com");
   mail.Subject = "New Survey Answer";
   mail.Body = "Answer 1:" + textBox1.Text + "Answer2:" + textBox2.text 
               + "Answer3": + textBox3.Text;
   SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

The problem is that when you run the `.exe` file of this program the antivirus believes this program is some kind of virus. Is there any way of preventing this?

Comment: talk to your system admins...

Comment: You can add the .exe of your program as a trusted application in the antivirus software.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to talk to the company producing your antivirus and send them a copy of your exe, so they can improve their product and you might gain some insight as to what the problem is.